# Error in Chisq.test() in R when there is only one row in the table

Tags: r

I have counting data that I want to run chisq.test() in R. The data has two variables and data type is binary. But, one variable has only one value "1", and another variable has values "0" or "1". So, the counting table is like this

> ```
>           0   1 
>      1  67   221
> ```

```
data1=matrix(c(67,211),nrow=1) 
rownames(data1)<-(1)
colnames(data1)<-c(0,1)
data1
chisq.test(data1)

            Chi-squared test for given probabilities
    data:  data1
    X-squared = 74.59, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16

chisq.test(data1)$p.value
[1] 5.793804e-18
```

However, if I add 2nd row with the count zero like below, and run chisq.test(), I got different result.

> ```
>           0   1 
>      1  67   221
>      0   0    0
> ```

```
data2=matrix(c(67,0, 211, 0), nrow=2, ncol=2) 
rownames(data2)<-c(1,0)
colnames(data2)<-c(0,1)
data2
chisq.test(data2)

           Chi-squared test for given probabilities
    data:  data2
    X-squared = NaN, df = 1, p-value = NA

chisq.test(data2)$p.value
[1] NaN
```

The data tables between 'data1' and 'data2' are the same counting data, but chisq.test() results are different.  The second result is correct; X-squared should be NaN and p-value should be NA because X-squared can't be calculated.

But, in my real data, one variable has only value '1' so when I imported the data txt file in R and converted to counting table, the 2nd row like data2 is not generated. So, chisq.test() is giving p-value 5.793804e-18. Is this R bug?

Sanghoon

Comment: It is not bug. From `?chisq.test`: "If x is a matrix with one row or column, or if x is a vector and y is not given, then a goodness-of-fit test is performed (x is treated as a one-dimensional contingency table). The entries of x must be non-negative integers. In this case, the hypothesis tested is whether the population probabilities equal those in p, or are all equal if p is not given." Thus, you first test is checking whether the data supports that probability that the counts 67 and 221 could come from a probability vector `c(0.5, 0.5)`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I could understand it. It is not a bug. Then, there is no way that I can get the variable which has value only "1" as non-significant variable in chisq.test()?   In my dataset, there are multiple variables (columns) and I ran chisq.test() on each variable for the last variable (column) to select dependent variables by significance p-value criteria.  But, some variables have only value "1" and they keep selected because the variable's p-value is 5.793804e-18.  Just I need to write extra code to remove those variables.

Comment: maybe use some branching like `if(length(unique(df[[i]])) < 2L) next else { ...}` where i is the column index and ... is the chi-square test. If you have a matrix already, you could use `if(min(dim(myMat)) == 1L)` where myMat is the name of the matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much your help again. Your explanation is very helpful. I think I solved every question I had thanks to your help!!